# Rails Include Third Party Javascript Library File

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, assets

I've got a Javascript library for AJAX file uploading that I need to include on only one page. Where is the best folder for this for file? `app/assets/javascripts`? `vendor/assets/javascripts`? `lib/assets/javascripts`? And then I need to be able to include it on only one page. Or should I just add it to `application.js` and have it included on every page (even know I'm only using it on one page?)

I figured for performance my best bet would be to put the minified JS file somewhere, and just include it with a `javascript_include_tag` on the page I need it, by using `yield(:head)` and `content_for(:head)`? Thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Third party JavaScripts should go inside `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory, because `app/assets/javscripts` is for your application specific JavaScripts and `lib/assets/javascripts` is for your libraries code which is separate to your application or libraries that you have shared across different applications.

Please reference [Asset Organization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) for further details.

As far as inclusion of javascripts in your application/page if you're using it only on a specific page then including the file with `javascript_include_tag` is the approach I would take as well.

Comment: Thanks. Do I keep it out of my application.js as well? I presume I should use the minified library and keep it out of application.js, and then use the yield to include it?

Comment: @b0xxed1n, sure minified library; out of `application.js` sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder `vendor/assets/javascripts` because is a folder for third party script